# Solving Recurrence Relatiion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have the recurrence relation:

$f(n) = f(n/2) + 1$ for all $n = 2^k$

and

$f(1) = 0$

To solve this recurrence relation is it okay to just use the master theorem and get that:

$f(n) = log_2(n)$

Thanks

Comment: You can easily show that $f(n) = \Theta(\log_2(n))$ but that exact result is not true.

Comment: @martycohen I added a base case, and the fact that every $n = 2^k$. Is the solution still invalid?

Comment: In this particular case, the solution you have is valid.

Comment: Restricting this to only $n=2^k$ means that this is really $g(k) = g(k-1)+1$ by letting $g(k) = f(2^k)$. The interesting case is for *all* $n$, not just $n=2^k$.